# Cannot import NUnit (already added via nuget)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm attempting to write tests with NUnit3 as part of some tech-debt migrations. I created a new project within an existing solution. Using nuget I added `NUnit` and `NUnit.Console` as per [the instructions on github](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Installation). (I also added the `NUnit 3 Test Adapter` extension to Visual Studio 2015, but I'm fairly sure that has no bearing on my current situation).

After adding the nuget packages I attempted to import the `TestFixture` attribute, however, visual studio isn't recognizing the `NUnit.Framework` namespace and I can't import anything.

The only thing I could thing to fix it was to add the reference manually. There too I was blocked by NUnit not being available.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to how to move forward. How do I proceed and fix the missing reference?

**Update**: The project I created was of type `Unit Test Project`, however I've gone ahead and create a `Console Application` and `Class Library`. I attempted to add NUnit via nuget to each of them and all of them have had the same result.

**Update**: Other nuget dependencies seem to install correctly with no discernable difference.

Comment: No it isn't. Nuget shows it as installed, but it's not added as a reference.

Comment: The project type is just a `Unit Test Project` (to my understanding, the only deviation from a `Class Library` project is that it includes `MSTest` as a reference). I can't take screenshots, unfortunately (why would be a protracted discussion about my employ), what information are you looking for specifically?

Comment: In adding the NUnit package, did you check the box for your test project? Does it now show as a referenced package if you use the management dialog in Visual studio and select the Installed tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a pseudo solution, as I don't know what the actual issue is. If anyone else comes across a better fix than my work-around I'll be glad to select it if it works for me down the line.

At the time of this writing, the latest version is `3.4.1`. I forced nuget to downgrade to `3.4.0` for both the packages `NUnit` and `NUnit.Console` and violà the namespace is available as you'd expect any nuget package.